# I overrode the clean() method in my django form, and fixed a bug that arose. But I dont understand how the bug was fixed

Tags: python, django, debugging, overriding

I am trying to add some validation into a form.

- Validation 1: quantity_moved should be above 0.
- Validation 2: source and destination must be different
- Validation 3: quantity_moved must be lower than the quantity at source location.

**Buggy Code**

```
# NOTE: Overriding the default method
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    source = str(cleaned_data['source'])
    destination = str(cleaned_data['destination'])
    quantity_moved = cleaned_data['quantity_moved']
    item = cleaned_data['item']

    # Checking if the source and destination are same
    if destination == source:
        msg = 'エラー：移動先と移動元が同じです。'
        self.add_error('source', msg)
        self.add_error('destination', msg)

    # Checking if the quantity to move is more than the current stock at the source location
    max_qty = ActualStock.objects.filter(item=item, location=cleaned_data['source'])[0].current_stock
    print(">" * 80, max_qty)

    if quantity_moved > max_qty:
        msg = "エラー：移動元に商品の数は足りません。現在, {0}に {1}の数は {2} です。".format(source, item, max_qty)
        self.add_error('quantity_moved', msg)
    return cleaned_data
```

Now, during testing if i enter same values for both source and destination(both are selected from respective dropdowns which points a same table in DB), I get a KeyError.

Now, if I change the order of the checks that I am performing as shown below, the code works.

**Working Code:**

```
# NOTE: Overriding the default method
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    source = str(cleaned_data['source'])
    destination = str(cleaned_data['destination'])
    quantity_moved = cleaned_data['quantity_moved']
    item = cleaned_data['item']

    # Checking if the quantity to move is more than the current stock at the source location
    max_qty = ActualStock.objects.filter(item=item, location=cleaned_data['source'])[0].current_stock
    print(">" * 80, max_qty)

    if quantity_moved > max_qty:
        msg = "エラー：移動元に商品の数は足りません。現在, {0}に {1}の数は {2} です。".format(source, item, max_qty)
        self.add_error('quantity_moved', msg)


    # Checking if the source and destination are same
    if destination == source:
        msg = 'エラー：移動先と移動元が同じです。'
        self.add_error('source', msg)
        self.add_error('destination', msg)

    return cleaned_data
```

Like I said, I managed to fix the bug but do not understand what fixed the bug here. Wondering if someone could shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django docs:

> Note that add_error() automatically removes the field from cleaned_data.

So in your first code sample, if destination equals source, you call **add_error** on both **source** and **destination**, and when you want to get source from **cleaned_data** as follows:

```
max_qty = ActualStock.objects.filter(item=item, location=cleaned_data['source'])[0].current_stock
```

You get a key error because **source** key was removed from **cleaned_data**

In your second sample you try to get source before calling add_error on it. You can solve this issue more reliably by changing this line of code

```
max_qty = ActualStock.objects.filter(item=item, location=cleaned_data['source'])[0].current_stock
```

To this:

```
max_qty = ActualStock.objects.filter(item=item, location=source)[0].current_stock
```